# Changing Ascii grid file inside a GeoJSON polygon

Tags: python, geojson, dem, esri-ascii-raster, gdalinfo

I have a Digital Terrain Model ASCII grid file that gdalinfo recognizes as AAIGrid. Its resolution is 2m. I need to alter it simulate the construction of an embankment, so as to feed it to a modelling software.

I can get the GeoJSON polygon for this embankment, as well as height, thickness and so on. What can I use to alter the terrain model file?

Comment: Since AAIGrid ist just a raster anything that can do band math should work - [gdal_calc](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) for example.

Comment: I believe gdal_calc needs to work on the whole file. I need to alter only a small part of it - the area inside the GeoJSON polygon.